# Kafka Streams (2.6) Standby Replica Expected Behavior on Rolling Restart

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Question regarding the specific behavior of Kafka Streams (2.6) in the context of state store restoration.  I currently have a topic with 50 partitions running 5 application instances (each with 30 configured threads (20 extra threads for the standby replicas); each instance is a Spring Boot app. instance).  I have configured 2 standby replicas for each instance:

i.e.

```
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.num.standby.replicas=2
```

after launching a load test with a fully saturated state store which just performs an aggregation previously saturated from a 4 hour load (the state store is approx. 250 GB in size at this point), hitting the 5 instances with 250 transactions per second, I bounce one of the instances.

At this point given the standby replicas configured is the expectation that the stream tasks for the bounced instance would just migrate to a standby replica on another instance and as the new instance comes up, would only migrate again to the new instance (but only when it was fully caught up)?

Based on KIP-441 (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-441%3A+Smooth+Scaling+Out+for+Kafka+Streams) and this (https://www.confluent.io/blog/cooperative-rebalancing-in-kafka-streams-consumer-ksqldb/) I thought that would be the case.

But currently seeing a rebalance where all the instances seem impacted and what's worse, it looks like some instances are taking several min. to restore.  Additionally, when I ran this test with no standby replicas, I only saw the cycled instance impacted and a restoration time of 55 sec. (it almost looked like the standby replicas made things worse).

Trying to determine where i'm missing something as I trust the documentation, but can't reconcile the current behavior.  For context this is the kstream in question:

```
   @Bean
   public Function<KStream<String, String>, KStream<String, AggregatedMessage>> aggregate() {
       Serde<AggregatedMessage> serializer = new JsonSerde<>(AggregatedMessage.class);
       return ks ->
               ks.peek((k, v) -> {
                   if (lastProcessed.get() != -1) {
                       long inactivity = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastProcessed.get();
                       eventMetrics.recordInterEventLatency(inactivity);
                   }
                   lastProcessed.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
                   eventMetrics.increment();
               })
                       .mapValues(this::map)
                       .filter((k, v) -> v != null)
                       .groupByKey()
                       .aggregate(AggregatedMessage::new, this::process,
                               Materialized.<String, AggregatedMessage, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as(aggregatedStateStore)
                                       // disabling in-memory caching ensures all k-table state changes are flushed to the internal
                                       // topic (relevant when performing join operations between two k-tables to ensures the cache
                                       // doesn't perform compaction in which case a join would result in possibly only the latest)
                                       // if you only care about eventual consistency, then enable caching...
                                       .withCachingDisabled()
                                       .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                                       .withValueSerde(serializer)
                                       .withLoggingEnabled(topicConfig))
                       .toStream();
   }
```

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.aggregate-in-0.destination=${aggregation-in-stream-topic}
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.aggregate-in-0.content-type=application/json
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.aggregate-in-0.consumer.header-mode=none
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.aggregate-in-0.consumer.concurrency=30

spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.replication.factor=3
spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.num.standby.replicas=2
```

Comment: Hey James, did you figure it out?

Comment: ^ I'm also interested in the solution